# Filter site pages , AllItems.aspx from Search results using search API powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, search-api

I have to get data from sharepoint tenant based on createdby using Search api powershell .In search results there are allitems.aspx and sitepages,Pages,Forms/Allitems.aspx,calendar.aspx also .How can i exclude these files from search results?

My query text is:
$queryText=" createdby:username AND NOT fileextension:html"
By above query text i can exclude only html files but not files mentioned above.How can i acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is :  - contentclass:STS_List_*

The slightly longer answer is to have a look at https://www.techmikael.com/2014/11/tired-of-getting-allitemsaspx-hits-in.html?m=1